# Why `spec-ARCHIVED.md` is removed from TypeScript repo?

Tags: typescript, apache, specifications

The `doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md` is removed in the https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51791, but I think the doc is very useful, sad for this and wanna know why...

I want to refer the doc in my own repo with APACHE 2.0 license, but I don't know if it's still available since it's been removed?

Comment: We can't really answer *why* it was removed.  But if you're asking if you can still see it, yes, you can look at old versions in GitHub.  [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3c99d50da5a579d9fa92d02664b1b66d4ff55944/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md) is the last version of spec-ARCHIVED.md before it was deleted.  Does that fully address the question?  Or am I missing something about what you're asking?